# Difference between ρ and ρ hat

Tags: correlation, descriptive-statistics

I was reading a paper where the author mentioned using ρ (correlation coefficient) and then the formal showing how to calculate correlation coefficient contained ρ hat. So I am wondering if these are the same or if there any difference between these two (ρ and ρ hat).

Comment: @Xi'an, thanks Xian thats all i needed. If you post your answer in the answer section, i can give you some points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With no link to or reproduction of the paper, it is impossible to answer precisely your question.

Usually, the convention in statistics is that a parameter $\rho$ is used for the model or the population, while the hat version $\hat\rho$ denotes the estimate based on the observed sample.

For instance, if we observe an iid sample $(x_1,y_1),\ldots,(x_n,y_n)$ from a distribution with correlation $\rho$, a converging estimate based on the observed sample is
$$\hat\rho=\dfrac{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\bar{x}_n)(y_i-\bar{y}_n)}{\left[\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\bar{x}_n)^2\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (y_i-\bar{y}_n)^2\right]^{1/2}}$$